# What is the Objective-C equivalent of Marshal.Copy

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin

I am rewriting a project from Xamarin(C#) to Native-iOS(Objective-C). My question is how to rewrite Marshall.Copy into Objective-C? Do we have a library that does the same functionality?

Xamarin

```
public void notifyCallBack(IntPtr someData, uint dataLength) {

       // Marshal data
       byte[] dataBuffer = new byte[dataLength];
       Marshal.Copy(someData, dataBuffer, 0, (int) dataLength);
}
```

Native iOS

```
void notifyCallBack(char* someData, uint dataLength) {
       //Marshal data
       unsigned char dataBuffer[sDataLen];
       ???


}
```

Comment: What does `Marshal.Copy` do?  Seems like it's just a `memcpy`?

Comment: memcpy. Just for curiosity - why are you going from C# to objective-c?

Comment: @armenm I have to rewrite a whole application written in Xamarin (C#) to integrate it as a feature in our application written in Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a new data buffer that contains a copy of the passed data, yes, you can do like people suggest - make a char[] buffer and do a [memcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcpy/), but that's a pure C-way (although nothing wrong with pure C).

The Objective-C way is to use [NSData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata?language=objc) (or [NSMutableData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutabledata?language=objc) if you want it to be writable):

```
NSMutableData *dataBuffer = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:someData length:dataLength];
```

This will be backed by a new memory block initialized with copied bytes (if you don't want to copy, there's another constructor).

Then use `dataBuffer.bytes` or `dataBuffer.mutableBytes` to access raw bytes as `void *` (which can be casted to `char *` for example).

Note that `new byte[]` was allocating on the heap (dynamic size), but the way you've declared `dataBuffer[sDataLen]` appears on the stack (and has fixed size). NSData is dynamic.